# Java Stream reduce ArrayList of generic types

Tags: java, java-stream, reduce

I have an ArrayList called "Catalog" of Articles (generic Type).

An Article has following Methods:

```
public int getUnitsInStore()
public long getUnitPrice()
```

To get the total value of all Articles within the catalog i try to use the Reduce Method of the Java Stream Api.

i tried following:

```
long value = 0;
    
value = catalog.stream().reduce((a,b) -> a.getUnitPrice()*b.getUnitsInStore());
```

But this is giving me the error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional<Article> to long
```

What im doing wrong?

Comment: read the doc for `reduce`: it will tell you what types a and b are, and what they represent exactly.

Comment: Your code makes no sense at all. Why would you multiply the price of one article with the unit count of an *entirely different* article? Sounds like what you need is `long total = catalog.stream().mapToLong(a -> a.getUnitPrice() * a.getUnitsInStore()).sum()`

Comment: @Andreas: Yeah, now i know. Thanks for comment. This helps a lot

Answer (score 2):

The `a` and `b` in your accumulator lambda are, respectively, the partial result and the next element in the stream. Since you are reducing over a list of Articles, the partial result is an Article and you cannot add a Long to an Article.

So in your case, you probably want to do something like this.

```
value = catalog.stream()
            .map(a -> a.getUnitPrice() * a.getUnitsInStore())
            .reduce(0L, Long::sum);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Know i understand

Comment: `.mapToLong(...).sum()` is probably more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of reduce methods.
Try this code to understand it better

```
    /**
     * T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)
     * 
     * identity = initial value
     * accumulator = first process initial value to first element of the stream,
     * then process the result with the next element in the stream
     */
     
    String name = Stream.of("T", "O", "M", "M", "Y")
            .reduce("", (a,n) -> a + n);
    System.out.println(name);
    
    int sum = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
            .reduce(0, (a,n) -> a + n);
    System.out.println(sum);

    int multi = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
            .reduce(1, (a,n) -> a * n);
    System.out.println(multi);
    
    
    /**
     * Optional<T> reduce(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)
     * 
     */
    
    Optional<String> optName = Stream.of("T", "O", "M", "M", "Y")
            .reduce((a,n) -> a + n);
    
    if(optName.isPresent()){
        System.out.println(" get from optional --> " + optName.get());
    } 
    
    /**
     * <U> U reduce​(U identity, BiFunction<U,​? super T,​U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)
     * 
     * This method signature is used when we are dealing with different types.
     * It allows Java to create intermediate reductions and then combine them at the end.
     */
    
    int total = Stream.of("R", "a", "z", "v", "a", "n")
        .reduce(0, (a,b) -> a + b.length(), (x,y) -> x + y);
    
            // 0 = initial value type int
            // a = int, must match the identity type
            // b.method() return type must match the a and the identity type
            // x,y from BinaryOperator 
    
    System.out.println(total);
    
    
    String names[] = {"Bobby", "Mark", "Anthony", "Danna"};
    
    int sumAll = Stream.of(names)
            .reduce(0, (a,b) -> a + b.length(), (x,y) -> x + y);
    System.out.println(sumAll);
    
    String csvNames = Stream.of(names)
            .reduce("", (a,b) -> a + b + ";");
    System.out.println(csvNames);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is really helpful

Comment: The third one might be a little tricky but give it a try

Comment: The 3 argument example is pretty bad, since it would be better implemented using `int total = Stream.of("R", "a", "z", "v", "a", "n").mapToInt(String::length).sum()`. The 3 argument version isn't used just to do a `map()` operation, it is used when the result is truly a different type, e.g. a `Collection` object, or a stats object for gathering multiple results, such as min, max, and average.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [`Stream.reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#i31) overload which expects two arguments:

- identity: The identity element is both the initial value of the reduction and the default result if there are no elements in the stream
- accumulator: The accumulator function which takes two parameters: a partial result of the reduction and the next element of the stream. It returns a new partial result.

Thus you will get your value using:

```java
value = catalog
        .stream()
        .reduce(0L, (partialSum, nextElement) -> partialSum + nextElement.getUnitPrice() * nextElement.getUnitsInStore());
```

Comment: The [`Stream.reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#i31) method expects 1, 2, or 3 arguments, depending on which overload is used. The question is trying to use the 1 argument version. If you want, you might *suggest* using the 2 argument version instead, and explain why you're suggesting that, but that's not what this answer is doing, so it is not a useful answer.

Comment: That is correct. In my opinion, the best choice would be the one with 2 args, so OP can define the initial value. I will update the answer to clarify that _one of the overloads expects two args_